# How to design this type of swappable card view with left and right side animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

How to design this type of swappable card view with left and right side animation in iOS?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: is there any reference library for this type of animation?

Comment: @Pankaj try this library:-https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @Purohit i already tried this but not getting proper result.

Answer (score 0):

You should always do your research on your own, there is a huge variety of Open Source Libraries and Developer SDKs which already support this kind of UI.

e.g. 5 seconds search in [awesome-ios](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios) lead to [this](https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose)